# CouchDB 2.1 /_db_updates respond with "Database does not exist."

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

It is a really strange behaviour, but there is no such endpoint as `/_db_updates`, however the documentation proves its existence.

CouchDB was installed by [this guide](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/install/mac.html).

Every major feature works (like the fauxton dashboard, db queries) but not the `/_db_updates` endpoints.

If I call the mentioned endpoint with the following command:

`curl http://<username>:<password>@localhost:5984/_db_updates`

I got back the following message:

`{"error":"not_found","reason":"Database does not exist."}`.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake, the error message misleaded me, but I found out, that I forgot to setup the corresponding database `_global_changes`.

[This guide](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/setup.html#install-setup) can help.